What is the integer literal suffix 'i' in C?
To my surprise, this code compiles with GCC 11.4.0 and i becomes 0:
#include <stdio.h>

int     main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        int i = 1i;
        printf( "i = %d\n", i );
        return 0;
}

I tried googling for the suffix i, but without success. In every description I've found only the usual ones are mentioned (e.g., in the answers to that Stack Overflow question).
I've also tried with all lower characters and other integer values and found that it's the same behaviour with j, and the value of my variable was always 0. With other suffixes like a, b, etc., it wouldn't compile.
So what is it that I've been stumbled upon? And is there a way to prevent GCC from compiling that or at least have some kind of diagnostics? In the 'real-world source' this happened because of a simple typo and of course resulted in run time errors.

1i is apparently interpreted as an imaginary number. See https://www.gnu.org/software/c-intro-and-ref/manual/html_node/Imaginary-Constants.html, for instance. Then, it is assigned to the i variable.

^^ And that same link explains j (which just means the same thing).

Either i or j suffix can be used in gcc to denote the imaginary part of a complex number (supported as a gcc extension) - see here. When you assign 1i to an int is becomes 0 because that's the real part of 1i.

I guess the typo was something like 123i instead of 123l.

the typo has been originated by typing one insert command to much in vi. It should have been plain 1 :-)

Regarding disabling the gcc extension to force a compilation error: you can check this - maybe it can help.

@wohlstad Can you provide a link where the last part of your comment is mentioned? (I am unable to find a proper reference and want to add it to my answer.)

@Harith I do not have a formal reference, it's just my common sense (1i is actually the the complex number 0 + 1i, and int is naturally a real number). BTW - I think your answer is useful and upvoted.

@Harith Off-site link describing how to do it correctly: What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?. The link by wohlstad above has some questionable answers. -pedantic -Werror and -pedantic-errors are not the same thing. The former means strict mode + turn all warnings into errors. The latter means strict mode + turn ISO C violation warnings into errors.

Re “I've also tried with all lower characters and other integer values and found that it's the same behaviour with j ant the value of my variable was always 0”: Trying with l or u would have given you 1.

@EricPostpischil of cause it gave me 1. I've left that out because I thought it was obxious

@Lundin: As the name "pedantic" suggests, the authors of gcc once recognized that arguments between those who saw certain constructs as useful and others who didn't like them was to say that implementations must output a diagnostic but could then process the construct usefully.  Such a decision doesn't represent a consensus view that such a diagnostic should be viewed as useful, but rather that people who viewed the construct as useful were willing to tolerate a useless but harmless diagnostic.  There are many situations where allowing char* to be treated as interchangeable with both...

...signed and unsigned character pointers would be more useful than requiring extra casts, but even people who recognized that were willing to accept that such diagnostics might sometimes be useful, and that implementations could allow programs to disable them when they would be useless.  Although void* is often better than char* as an argument type, it annoyingly needs to be converted to a character type before it can actually used to access storage.

@supercat Except that is not how engineering works. Engineering works through industry standards - you have a group of domain experts set a standard and then everyone follows it, no matter if they agree or not. Engineering is not about democracy and everyone having their say, it is about producing products that are safe and work for their intended purpose. The vast majority of the world's population does not have a clue about how to build a compiler, or a computer program, or a car, or a toothbrush. But they put their trust into engineers to do that.  ->

And in the real world where computer programs are executed, there are laws and directives set out by governments, which in turn point towards technical standards and say "hey, if you aren't following these standards you better have a damn good reason or what you are doing might even be considered illegal". This is necessary so we can have safe cars, safe bridges and safe computer programs. ->

Now if some hobbyists feels that they know better than everyone else and decides to cook up a program which does not follow engineering best practices, but something else, that's their choice. They may call themselves hobbyists or cowboys or whatever they like, just not engineers. I don't think those who dismiss following technical standards as "pedantic" have ever built a safety-critical product in their life. Well I have, and I need to be able to sleep at night knowing that I haven't been playing lottery with people's life just because I liked to invent useless gcc extension #555.

@Lundin: The C Standard characterizes as conforming any C program that is accepted by any conforming C implementation elsewhere in the universe, and it allows conforming C implementations to accept any source text that does not have an #error directive survive preprocessing.  Had it characterized as non-conforming many of the constructs language purists today claim are non-conforming, it would have been soundly rejected by language users, much as "Standard Pascal" was rejected in favor of dialects like Turbo Pascal and MPW Pascal.

@Lundin: Have you read the published Rationale for the C99 Standard (which covers C89 design decisions as well)?  It's pretty clear the authors intended to leave many decisions to "the marketplace" (presumably consisting of people seeking to sell compilers to the people writing code for them).  You may say that's not how standards are supposed to work, and I would agree, but it's what the Committee wrote.  Trying to interpret it as something it was never meant to be makes it worse than useless.

@supercat I have and I also had the chance to chat with someone who was on the C89 committee. And they said that one of the main obstacles the committee was facing was that the standards weren't allowed to favour one existing technology over another no matter the market share. So it wasn't as much as that they wanted to leave things open, as the standard institute(s) forcing them to do so. And that's how utter BS like implementation-defined signedness made it into the standard in the first place, making C a worse language as a result. It took more than 30 years to fix that nonsense.

@Lundin: Another issue is that there are some corner cases which are sometimes useful and can sometimes occur as a result of erroneous code, and which some implementations could be configured to trap (in cases where they weren't done deliberately).  A prime example, would be, given char arr[5][3];, the behavior of arr[i][j] or *(arr[i]+j) when j is in the range 3 to 14.  Trapping if j exceeds 2 when code is the former way is sometimes useful, but the ability to treat arrays as "flattened" is fundamental to C.  The Standard makes no distinction, however.

From GNU docs:

The simple way to write an imaginary-number constant is to attach the
suffix ‘i’ or ‘I’, or ‘j’ or ‘J’, to an integer or floating-point
constant. For example, 2.5fi has type _Complex float and 3i has type
_Complex int. The four alternative suffix letters are all equivalent...Standard C doesn’t support suffixing with ‘i’ or ‘j’.

So we can conclude:

ISO C Standard doesn't support i, I, j, or J suffixes. These suffixes are a GCC extension.

i, j, I, and J are equivalent.

Attaching any of the aforementioned suffixes to an integer or floating-point constant makes it an imaginary-number constant.


This GNU extension is also supported by Clang.
Compiling with -pedantic-errors fails:
$ gcc c.c -pedantic-errors -o c
c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:5:17: error: imaginary constants are a GCC extension
    5 |         int i = 1i;
      |                 ^~

$ clang c.c -pedantic-errors -o c
c.c:5:17: error: imaginary constants are a GNU extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-imaginary-constant]
        int i = 1i;
                ^
1 error generated.

See also: What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?.
As of why i became 0:
From section 6.3.1.7 of the ISO C Standard regarding Real and Complex conversions:

When a value of real type is converted to a complex type, the real part of the complex
result value is determined by the rules of conversion to the corresponding real type and the imaginary part of the complex result value is a positive zero or an unsigned zero.
When a value of complex type is converted to a real type, the imaginary part of the complex value is discarded and the value of the real part is converted according to the conversion rules for the corresponding real type.

So when you assign 1i to an int, it becomes 0 because the that's the real part of 1i, and the imaginary part is discarded.
ISO C does support I for the imaginary part (although it is not a suffix, and is a constant and requires multiplication; like 3 + 4*I), although support for complex.h and complex numbers is optional for the compiler. The compiler may define __STDC_NO_COMPLEX__ if it does not support such.
From the ISO C Standard, 7.3.1 Introduction:

....
The macro
I
expands to either _Imaginary_I or _Complex_I. If _Imaginary_I is not
defined, I shall expand to _Complex_I.
¶7 Notwithstanding the provisions of 7.1.3, a program may undefine and
perhaps then redefine the macros complex, imaginary, and I.

As of the suffixes a, b, et cetera, neither the ISO C Standard, nor the GNU C Standard has support for any such thing.

ISO C does support I for the imaginary part, although support for complex.h and complex numbers is optional for the compiler. The compiler may define __STDC_NO_COMPLEX__ if it does not support such. There are two problems here: 1) gcc doesn't follow standard C by default and 2) it comes with an implementation of complex numbers which doesn't follow standard C either, but instead breaks conforming C programs (with or without complex.h).

@Lundin I cannot find I suffix in C17 draft. Only I from complex.h which is not a suffix but constant and requires multiplication; like 3 + 4*I.

@user694733 True, it is not a suffix (and I actually didn't say that it is). But still a reserved identifier which a conforming C compiler is explicitly not allowed to redefine to something else.

The gcc compiler unfortunately comes in "safety hazard mode" by default, since it is by default using a non-standard superset of the C language called GNU C (-std=gnu17).
The GNU C language contains a lot of things that are in direct conflict with conforming C. It also contains lots of non-standard alternative features to things that already exist in standard, such as imaginary number support, flexible array members, alignment specifiers etc etc. In GNU mode, gcc is happy to let such things pass silently, even if they are non-conforming C or breaks a conforming C program.
In this case you happened to stumble upon the GNU extension for complex numbers where i is a non-standard imaginary part suffix. This is a different one than the complex number implementation introduced by the C99 standard.
If you care about C language conformance, you should always compile with -std=c17 -pedantic-errors.

Another useful response to that
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    //declaring a complex number using complex
    double complex z1 = 1 + 2*I;

    //Arithmetic operation
    z1 = 2 * z1;

    //Printing correct to 1dp
    printf("2 * (1.0+2.0i) = %.1f%+.1fi\n", creal(z1), cimag(z1));

    //declaring a complex number using _Complex
    double _Complex z2 = 3 + 4*I;

    //Arithmetic operation
    z2 = 1 / z2;

    //Printing correct to 1dp
    printf("1 / (3.0+4.0i) = %.1f%+.1fi\n", creal(z2), cimag(z2));
}

src: educative.io
I also recommend cppreference.com
The catch here is the way the integer i is initialized. Specifically, 1i is not a valid integer literal in C. The compiler interprets 1i as a combination of 1 (an integer) and i (an imaginary unit in complex number notation, which is not applicable in this context).
In C, an invalid suffix for a numeric constant is ignored, and the default value of the variable i ends up being 0 because it was not properly initialized. Hence, the statement int i = 1i; results in i being set to 0.

I have been programming C for almost 40 years now and must admit: This question caught me off-guard.
There is no integer suffix.
In 6.4.4.1, "Integer Constants", of the C23 draft, the syntax of an integer constant is given as

decimal-constant integer-suffixopt

The suffix is defined as

integer-suffix:
                  unsigned-suffix long-suffixopt
                  unsigned-suffix long-long-suffix
                  unsigned-suffix bit-precise-int-suffix
                  long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
                  long-long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
                  bit-precise-int-suffix unsigned-suffixopt

You can see that a "normal plain int suffix" is not among them. An int constant is a decimal integer literal whose value x satisfies INT_MIN <= x <= INT_MAX.
The reason is certainly that int is the "normal case"; only special cases would need a syntax.
That is quite unsatisfying because, say, the type of 32768 is implementation specific. On machines with 16 bit ints, it would have type long int. In that case, e.g. printf("%d", 32768) would be wrong.
Admittedly, that isn't as bad as in C++ where function overloading can make the specific type more important. And of course, you can always write (int)32768 (but I suppose many compilers would not warn of a narrowing conversion here because with an explicit cast, the programmer is responsible).

"I have been programming C for almost 40 years now and must admit: This question caught me off-guard." This seems to summarize C's language design quite well.
